# How to set random image in a gridview layout of 3*3

Tags: android

Hi friends I am making Tic Tac Toe app.
I want to make it computer vs Player mode currently it is in a two player mode.
getting confused in how to set the input in `Gridview` layout as a `ImageView`.

```
    int activePlayer = 0;

            boolean gameIsActive = true;

            // 2 means unplayed 0 means computer and 1 means Player moves

            int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

            public void dropIn(View view) {

                ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

                int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

                if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameIsActive) {

                    gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

                    counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

                    if (activePlayer == 0) {
                            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                            activePlayer = 1;
                    } 
        else {

                        counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);

                        activePlayer = 0;

                    }

                counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(360).setDuration(300);
}
```

XML FILE

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="3"   />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="4" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="5"   />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="6" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="7"   />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="8" />

</GridLayout>
```

I want to chose `activeplayer=0` image randomly?

Comment: NO! No! NO! Not a good programming practice, and you can't even achieve your obj like that. you can simply Define an int array of `DrawableRes` for your images.

Comment: You only need 1 `imageView`, then Define an int array of `DrawableRes`, after that  you can generate random number (whichever ways you wanna generate your number as an index for the images in `DrawableRes`).

Comment: That should be fine if he has fixed layout grid of 3x3. Just needs to attach the same click listener for for all 9 buttons.

Comment: can any one explain me where I am wrong please.

Comment: @K132133SyedArsalanHussain you are not wrong just have answered of your query **How to set random image for activeplayer=0**

Answer (score 0):

Define an int array of `DrawableRes` and access using random number. For random number generation use the answer of user "I need a job"

```
@DrawableRes int [] activePlayerRes = new int [] {R.drawable.yellow,....};
```

After all you have use change your call like

```
counter.setImageResource(activePlayerRes[randomRes]); // make sure your random should return in range of array you defined.
```

Comment: Exactly what i asked